# onSubscribe comes too late when using fromCallable

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the quite frequent requirement to execute some logic at onSubscribe and at onFinally, which can conviniently achieved via

```
private <T> Mono<T> doAtStartAndEnd(Mono<T> source) {
  return source.doOnSubscribe((s) -> {
      System.out.println("ON SUBSCRIBE");
    }).doFinally((f) -> {
      System.out.println("ON FINALLY");
    });
}
```

and using it via `transform` in the following chain:

```
List<String> result = Mono.fromCallable(() -> getListOfStrings())
// .log()
  .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
  .map(String::toUpperCase)
  .collectList()
  .transform(this::doAtStartAndEnd)
  .block();
```

The expected behavior is of course, that `ON SUBSCRIBE` appears in the console, before the invocation of the callable, here `getListOfStrings()`. However the subscribe logic of `MonoFlattenIterable` leads to the opposite behavior. This is not only the case for `flatMapIterable`, but also for various other operators like `zip`.

If I uncomment the line with `.log()` the chain behaves as expected.

Maybe this is exactly the same as in  [Reactive Gem #22](https://github.com/reactor/reactive-streams-commons/issues/21#issuecomment-222080500), but then how can I achieve the desired behavior, without wrapping the Mono/Flux again, e.g. in `Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> getListOfStrings()))`?

Comment: I believe the problem is the `flatMapIterable`. It seems that if `onSubscribe` is placed after `flatMapIterable` then the event is triggered after the it has managed to produce the list (which of course is after the invocation of `getListOfStrings`). If you place `onSubscribe` before the `flatMapIterable` then everything happens as you would expect. Not sure if this is documented somewhere or if it is a bug though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMapIterable` tries to avoid doing a full blown RS subscription-and-request cycle to get the `Iterable` when the source is detected as `Callable`. Instead, it directly invokes the `call()` method.

This is fine for cases like `Flux.just(myList).flatMapIterable(list -> list)`. However, I think it might be overeager to do that on `Mono.fromCallable`...

One way of suppressing the detection of your `Mono.fromCallable()` for this optimization is to use `.hide()` after it. As for `.log()` this changes the instance that is visible to `flatMapIterable` to something that is NOT `Callable`.